# How to reference Source Code

Tags: citations, online-resource, code

I'm writing a paper on a technique which I have implemented in open source software. I'd like to reference the location of the open source software and the code I implemented for the technique so as to increase reproducibility of my findings.

I was thinking of adding a sentence somewhere along the lines of "Note that the source code can be found at github.com/..." or "Note that the implementation is open source.\ref{myrepository}"
Which format is best?

I don't know where to put this line. In the introduction, the method description or the algorithm section? Other options would be the conclusion or the acknowledgements.

Comment: If you want, you can even make a specific release of your code citable with a DOI. See https://guides.github.com/activities/citable-code/ for more information.

Comment: @mhwombat Thanks, but I'd like to know where and how to reference the bib item containing the DOI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the link where your readers will find it most easily, i.e. as early in the document as possible. A link to your repository in the introduction would be ideal. Placing an identical reference elsewhere in your paper wouldn't hurt - nothing is worse than having to hunt through a paper just to find the single github link.

Similarly, the exact format should be conducive to finding your code, so a direct link is likely easier to follow. A formal reference may work better if you reference the repository several times within the manuscript.